# How to have footer always at the bottom of page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, sticky-footer

My page doesn't contain a lot of information, so footer is displayed somewhere in the middle of the page. How can I have that always at the bottom?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/9eYa8/ if you mean your query is regarding HTML.

Comment: Thanks, my question was about jquery mobile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

jquery mobile approach - `<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">`

Comment: This doesn't help me for the case when my page is longer than the mobile viewport.  I would like the footer to be fixed for short content pages, but be at the very bottom of the content for longer pages, not overlayed on top of content.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
  potition: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: some_height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've just found jquery mobile approach - `<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a fixed position footer. The footer will be offscreen if the page content is taller than the screen. I think it looks better this way.

The body and .ui-page min-height and height are necessary to prevent the footer from jumping up and down during transitions.

Works with the latest JQM version as of now, 1.4.0

```
body,
.ui-page {
    min-height:100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
}

.ui-content {
    margin-bottom:42px; /* HEIGHT OF YOUR FOOTER */
}

.ui-footer {
    position:absolute !important;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
[data-role=footer]{bottom:0; position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; width:100%;}
```